# libAppProtection.so File deleted

Tags: filesystem, system

I erroneously deleted the libappprotation.so file, in Ubuntu 20.04, now I have the error: `ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libappprotation.so' from /etc/ld.so.prolead cannot be preloaded (cannot open Shared Object File): Ignored.` When I reboot or install something.

How can I restore/recreate the `libappprotation.so` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [not](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libappprotation.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any) a file that ships in any Ubuntu package. A brief online search suggests it's probably part of [Citrix App Protection.](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2021/08/23/introducing-app-protection-in-citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/) Maybe reinstall that?